# Interpretation of clusplot graph, first two PCA components only explain 50% variance

Tags: clustering, interpretation

Can the clusplot graph still be used as a 2D representation of the cluster results if the first two components only explain ~50% of the total variance.

[image]

Also, is it true that the points lying on the boundary of each cluster ellipse is a potential outlier for cluster. Using this graph for example, even if the first 2 PCA components only explain 50% of the variance, can i still say many of the points could belong in either cluster 1 or 2.

Any guidance for plot interpretations would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there are *two* clusters? I'd guess there is only one cluster there.

Comment: well the data didnt converge but gap statistic method gave 2 clusters

Comment: these statistics may be misleading. In particular, when you are really trying hard to make something cluster that doesn't.

Comment: Clustering techniques will always make clusters and the strength of evidence (e.g., "significative") depends on the amount of data points and not (only) on the importance of the separation. Is this an indirect analysis? (you did a PCA to retain most of data variation in less dimensions and then clustered the data points with the first two axes). Then you have to be aware that: (1) goal of PCA is different than clustering (does not maximize the degree of separation); (2) you are clustering with "half of the evidence" [very roughly speaking] you had at the beginning in your multivariate data set

Comment: DJ_, your question is bound by your data and cannot be answered in an abstract mode. People here doubt that your data do split in real clusters. Think of giving us your data, like - to check it.